# Getting error java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: pBuffers

Tags: java, single-sign-on, jna, glassfish-4, waffle

I'm trying to implement SSO (using [waffle](https://github.com/Waffle/waffle)) in Glassfish 4 . I'm using following jars in Java + Glassfish (I have tweaked glassfish to use JNA 5.5):

- jna-5.5.0.jar
- jna-platform-5.5.0.jar
- waffle-jna-1.9.0.jar (tried with
  2.2 as well)

As soon as I call constructor ManagedSecBufferDesc , I'm getting error as java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: pBuffers

```
do {

    if (serverContext != null) {

        // initialize on the client

        SecBufferDesc continueToken = new SspiUtil.ManagedSecBufferDesc (Sspi.SECBUFFER_TOKEN, serverContext.getToken());
        clientContext.initialize(clientContext.getHandle(), continueToken , securityPackage);
    }

    // accept the token on the server
    serverContext = provider.acceptSecurityToken(securityPackage, clientContext.getToken(), "Negotiate");

} while (clientContext.isContinue() || serverContext.isContinue());
```

Can someone please help ?

Comment: Can't reproduce this. Have you tried rebuilding your maven dependency tree?

Comment: Okay this can be closed , multiple old files found in setup , clearing those helped me solve the problem .